# Confusion about extension method

Tags: c#, this

I have a question about extension method.I write following code:

```
public static List<TxCurve> Sort(this List<TxCurve> fubanCenters, List<TxCurve> sortedPillar, TxCurve roadCenter)
{
    List<TxCurve> sortedCurve = new List<TxCurve>();
    // do something ...

    fubanCenters = sortedCurve; //change fubanCenters
    return fubanCenters;
}
```

use the extension method:

```
//use extension method
centers.Sort(sortedPillar, roadCenter);
```

But after execute above code, the centers doesn't change, Why? please tell me, thank you.

Comment: after sort like any other method its returns `List<TxCurve>` so `List<TxCurve> sortedTxCurve=centers.Sort(sortedPillar, roadCenter);` is that what you are missing?

Comment: Try `centers = centers.Sort(sortedPillar, roadCenter);`

Comment: if you want to replace your fubanCenters you have to use REF before List<TxCurve> fubanCenters, and remove "this". i think ref extension methods are not possible yet

Comment: @ Avinash Reddy Thank you for answer my question, your answer is correct, but I want to know why `centers.Sort(sortedPillar, roadCenter);` not work, I have change fubanCenters in method.`fubanCenters = sortedCurve; //change fubanCenters`

Comment: For the same reason that `sortedPillar = sortedCurve` wouldn't work. Both variables are local copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `// do something...` does not actually affect the list that is being extended, we refer to this type of method as a *Function* and may even refer to it as *Immutable*.

Because this method performs an operation and returns the result, when you call the function, you will need to save the results before you can use them, as suggested by @Collen

```
List<TxCurve> sortedCenters = centers.Sort(sortedPillar, roadCenter);
```

If instead your intention was for the Sort to act on the list, then you could change the extension method definition as either of the following:

```
public static void Sort(this List<TxCurve> fubanCenters, List<TxCurve> sortedPillar, TxCurve roadCenter)
{
    List<TxCurve> sortedCurve = new List<TxCurve>();
    // do something ...

    fubanCenters.Clear();
    fubanCenters.AddRange(sortedCurve); //change fubanCenters
}
```

or if you intend to support chaining syntax, you could also return a reference to the extended list:

```
public static List<TxCurve> Sort(this List<TxCurve> fubanCenters, List<TxCurve> sortedPillar, TxCurve roadCenter)
{
    List<TxCurve> sortedCurve = new List<TxCurve>();
    // do something ...

    fubanCenters.Clear();
    fubanCenters.AddRange(sortedCurve); //change fubanCenters
    return fubanCenters;
}
```

> The reason that `fubanCenters = sortedCurve;` does not work is that in the context of the extension method the vairable called `fubanCenters` is only a reference to the object, it is not a pointer to the actual object.
>   By assigning a new value to the `fubanCenters` variable, you are actually replacing the previous reference with a reference to the new object.
>
> > To prove this phenonenon, with your existing code the following will evaluate to false.
> >         
> >     `//use extension method
> >     var result = centers.Sort(sortedPillar, roadCenter);
> >     var areEqual = result == centers;`

Answer (score 1):

The question was: why?
So, the `fubarCenters` is the pointer parameter, represented as local variable. You replaced value of this parameter by `sortedCurve` only locally, it means it starts pointing the new list only locally.

To make this change visible outside, try this:

```
public static List<TxCurve> Sort(this List<TxCurve> fubanCenters, List<TxCurve> sortedPillar, TxCurve roadCenter)
{
    List<TxCurve> sortedCurve = new List<TxCurve>();
    // do something ...

    fubanCenters.Clear();
    fubanCenters.AddRange(sortedCurve); //change fubanCenters
    return fubanCenters;
}
```

Comment: In that case, I'd think that changing the method to `void` might be preferable to returning `List<TxCurve>`, since returning `List<TxCurve>` could incorrectly hint that `fubanCenters` is not mutated by the method.